# Not understanding C++ Template Specialization And Constants

Tags: c++11, templates, specialization, variadic

I am trying to wrap my head around template specialization, and I am a bit confused (perhaps not understanding what typename actually is, or what the compiler expects)

**Example 1 (Compiles):**

```
template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example
{
public:
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};

template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example<A, int, Args...>{
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};
```

**Example 2 (Compiles):**

```
template <typename A, int, typename... Args>
class Example
{
public:
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};

template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example<A, 2, Args...>{
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};
```

**Example 3 (Fails):**

```
template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example
{
public:
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};

template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example<A, 2, Args...>{
    Example(){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};
```

The error is:

*error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template class Example*

**Questions:**

First, I am new to generic programming, and I hope I am asking the right questions. The compiler spec terminology is still a bit foreign to me.

- What is happening? Is the compiler trying to treat the constant as
  typename?
- If typename can be specialized as int, and int can be specialized as 2, why can't a typename be specialized as 2?
- What would be a "proper" method to specialize the class with int or enum?
- Am I asking the right questions?

Thank you

**EDIT/Solution:**

After I understood what is going on (from Yakk's explanation), here is how my final solution looks like. I read somewhere by one of the C++ guru's that "You can solve any problem by adding another layer of abstraction". Now I know what that means :D

```
 enum ETypes
{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    INT = 1,
    FLOAT = 2,
    STRING = 3,
    FUNC = 4,
};

// This is to use the ETypes as a type.
// Note that T is not a type, hence use it as RHS
template<ETypes T>
class ETypeName
{
public:
    ETypes type = T;
};


// The example
template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example
{
private:
    Example();              // Hide the constructor as private
                            // to generate compilation error
    virtual ~Example(){}
};


// LOOK! We can use the Enum to specialize the class.
template <>
class Example<ETypeName<ETypes::INT>>{
public:
    ETypes mType;
    Example():mType(ETypes::INT){}
    virtual ~Example(){}
};
```

**And in main():**

```
    Example<ETypeName<ETypes::INT>> x;

    // This can't happen. Private constructor. Not specialized yet
//  Example<ETypeName<ETypes::FLOAT>> x1;
```

Comment: Non-type template parameters are different from type template parameters. In essence yes, the 2 is treated as an non-type parameter but the template class expects a type.

Comment: Ah, so that is something I was missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary specialization looks like this:

```
template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example
```

When you type `Example<stuff goes here>`, it is *always* matched against the primary specialization's `<typename A, typename... Args>` argument list.

This is a completely different beast:

```
template <typename A, typename... Args>
class Example<A, int, Args...>
```

This is a secondary specialization.  Here,

```
template <typename A, typename... Args>
```

is *not* the argument list, but rather the deduction list.

The argument list is:

```
class Example<A, int, Args...>
```

here.  What is between the `<>` is only used to **pattern match** against arguments passed to the primary specialization.

Types and non-type template parameters are different things.  The primary specialization details what arguments are type, and what arguments are non-type.

Once they have matched against the primary, each of the secondary specializations are pattern matched against the arguments.  Each viable candidate is examined, and a reasonably complex system is used to determine which is "more specialized", the rules of which I won't go into here.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer for clarifying the definitions and terminology and explaining how they work at a deeper level which I wasn't exposed to.

Answer (score 2):

> What is happening? Is the compiler trying to treat the constant as typename?

Yes.

> If typename can be specialized as int, and int can be specialized as 2, why can't a typename be specialized as 2?

A template parameter starting with `typename` requires a type as argument. In your second example, the second template parameter is `int`, not `typename something`. As such, it does not expect a type as argument, but an actual `int` value.

Your third example uses a template definition that only expects `typename` template parameters, but you try and give it an `int` value as argument. This is why you get the error.

> What would be a "proper" method to specialize the class with int or enum?

Not sure I understand the meaning of the question properly. The proper way to specialize your template for instances using an `int` second template parameter is your second template definition.